# How to upload files to REST in c#

Tags: c#, file, rest, file-upload

I am trying to call a REST api to upload files as parameters. I am able to hit the rest service using the below code.But i am not able to pass file object. I am able to pass a string to the api using the code.

This code is hitting the server. The c# code is as follows.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var collection = new NameValueCollection();
                collection["para1"] = "C:\\abc.txt"; 
                collection["para2"] = "C:\\file2.doc";
                collection["para3"] = "C:\\ab.jpg";
                collection["details"] = "C:\\det.txt";

                var response = client.UploadValues("http://192.168.1.23:8555/upload", collection);

                var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
            }
```

what is wrong here?

I am able to do the same thing in postman rest client also. 
If i do this to make value of para1 as a file object,it is giving error as both name and value should be string. How can i call the REST with file objects as parameters.

```
collection["para1"] = File.read("C:\\abc.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [MSDN documentation of Webclient.UploadValues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7(v=vs.110).aspx) this is a method used to upload the specified name/value collection to the resource identified by the specified URI. In your case you need to upload collection of files for that you will have to use the [UploadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.110).aspx) method of web client while iterating over your NamedValueCollection to upload your files which means some thing like this:

```
foreach (var item in collection )
    var response = client.UploadFile("http://192.168.1.23:8555/upload", item.value);
```